# jQuery Get the Next Set of Classes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML like

```
<body>
   <div class="myCool">blah</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="myCool">blah</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
</body>
```

What am I trying to do is start at `myCool` and wrap it and the next 4 classes `cool` into a `div` ? So it looks like

```
 <div id="1" class="myWrapped">
   <div class="myCool">blah</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
 </div>
 <div id="2" class="myWrapped">
   <div class="myCool">blah</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
   <div class="cool">some text</div>
 </div>
```

Any ideas how I can do this ?

Comment: ID attributes always ought to start with a letter: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$(".myCool").each(function(i){
  $(this).nextUntil(".myCool").andSelf().wrapAll("<div id='" + (i+1) + "' class='myWrapped'></div>");
});
```

Comment: nice solution, forgot the id though!

Comment: You sir - are a legend! Thanks - it was the `.andSelf()` that I was missing :) Adding the `id` would be preferred also ? How about like
`.each(function(i)} ..... <div id="' + i + '" ...`

Comment: @KevinB - just a question - if I only wanted to do it for 1 "set" ? How would I go about that ? i.e. from `.mycool` to `.cool` x4 but no 2nd etc i.e. need to like use something like .next('cool')` for 4x or something or ?

Comment: @Andy - Just don't use the `.each`. `$(".myCool").nextUntil(".myCool").etc...`

Comment: @KevinB - thanks for response! no but I mean - if I don't have a next `.myCool` - i.e. i only have `.myCool, .cool x4`

Comment: @Andy - `nextUntil` in that case should get all of the remaining elements after `.myCool`. Take this fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/pnYhZ/ It is doing what you are describing on the second set.

Comment: @KevinB - more like http://jsfiddle.net/pnYhZ/3/. i.e. there is only one set and I need to wrap this entirely ?

Comment: @Andy - you had a typo, http://jsfiddle.net/pnYhZ/4/ the classname was missing a `.`

Answer (score -2):

you can do like this

```
jQuery("<div class='myCool'>blah</div>").appendTo('body');
for(var i=0; i<4;i++)
{
    jQuery('<div class="cool">some text</div>').appendTo('.myCool');
}
```

Comment: **-1** Doesn't answer the question at all